# Good uses for sweet whey

Tags: food

I make cheese from time to time which produces copious quantities of whey (often more than I can drink in the mean time).

Are there any extra uses for whey that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Milk and milk products including whey were the basic food (along with cereal products) of our ancestors, so there must be even more ways to use it than this link indicates:

[16 Ways to Use Your Whey](http://www.theprairiehomestead.com/2011/06/16-ways-to-use-your-whey.html)

EDIT: to sum up the link, there are plenty of ways how it be used for food, such as to substitute it for water while baking. It can also be fed to animals.

What is not in the link: whey was (and still is) fermented for an alcoholic drink, but I din't find any handbook to homebrew it.